# How to fix ipython-kernel-install: error: unrecognized arguments:

Tags: installation, jupyter-notebook, miniconda

I'm installing jupyter notebook on miniconda, using this link: https://gist.github.com/saharctech/8e686dd04d2a490894837e182be769de

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnZRy.png)
I would then run into this error:  ipython-kernel-install: error: unrecognized arguments: -user -name=ENVIRONMENT-NAME

Would anyone know how I can resolve this please? Thank you!